# how to create a percona instance or Percona XtraDB Cluster in openstack trove?

Tags: openstack, percona

when create percona using:

```
netID=$(openstack network list | grep GREEN | awk '{ print $2 }') && echo $netID
openstack database instance create  \
--flavor 2C_2G_20G  \
--size 4 \
--nic net-id=$netID \
--databases test \
--users app:pass123 \
--datastore percona --datastore-version 5.7 \
--is-public \
percona_1
```

there is error log at guest vm :

```
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 CRITICAL root [-] Unhandled error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trove.guestagent.datastore.experimental'
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root   File "/usr/local/bin/guest-agent", line 10, in <module>
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root     sys.exit(main())
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root   File "/opt/guest-agent-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trove/cmd/guest.py", line 94, in main
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root     rpc_api_version=guest_api.API.API_LATEST_VERSION)
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root   File "/opt/guest-agent-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/trove/common/rpc/service.py", line 48, in __init__
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root     _manager = importutils.import_object(manager)
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root   File "/opt/guest-agent-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_utils/importutils.py", line 44, in import_object
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root     return import_class(import_str)(*args, **kwargs)
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root   File "/opt/guest-agent-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oslo_utils/importutils.py", line 30, in import_class
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root     __import__(mod_str)
2021-11-05 15:52:59.693 2097 ERROR root ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trove.guestagent.datastore.experimental'
```

How to enable trove to use percona ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem with deploying redis. I'm using wallaby release of trove. Looks like the experimental datastore managers were removed in the victoria release, not sure why yet. They are still there in the ussuri release. See here: https://opendev.org/openstack/trove/src/branch/stable/ussuri/trove/guestagent/datastore/experimental

I wonder if the intention is for you to add them yourself via a custom guest image or something.

EDIT: Here's the review entry for the change: https://review.opendev.org/c/openstack/trove/+/728419

Looks like a bunch of functionality was clobbered. Again, unsure why.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for your reply, we had cut off mysql cluser in trove release of victoria